# Rails - how to ignore validations for a nested object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to collect information about a **Physician**. Each **Physician** can have at least one **Address** but it's ok for a physician not to have any address.

Below is the relevant code from my **physician.rb** and **model.rb** files that define the respective models.

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  validates :line_1, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
```

**Address** has some required fields, `line_1`, and `city`

I would like to ignore the `presence` requirement on these fields ONLY for the **Physician** form.

I tried using the `optional: true` tag (shown in the code above) but that didn't do it.

Comment: I feel like there's a few weird things with this setup. First I'd think an `Address` should `belong_to` a `Physician`, not the other way around. Second, it sounds like a `Physician` should be able to have more than 1 `Address`? If so this should be a `has_many` relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to change the following line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

to

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: :all_blank
```

so the associated `Address` object will be completely ignored if all of its attributes are left blank.